# Why haven't I earned the Guru badge?

Tags: support, badges, self-answer, guru-badge

According to StackOverflow's [badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=general&filter=all), one can earn the Guru badge with an accepted answer with a score of 40 or more. As of the time of this writing, I have an accepted answer with a score of 41 on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276967/python-in-xcode-4). Why have I not earned the badge? [Link to my badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/652722/tyler-crompton?tab=badges&sort=name).

**EDIT**: According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399), I should have attained it. Whatever the exception is, it should be documented to avoid confusion.

Comment: It's community wiki. I'm not sure, but I think CW answers don't count for badges.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder when that happened.

Comment: CW posts definately count for badges just not for rep. Self accepts don't count for rep or badges.

Comment: Guru __can__ be awarded for CW answers. Bill Karwin [earned Guru for his answer to "Has anyone 'learned how to program in 21 days?'"](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/18/guru?userid=20860), which [is CW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441198/has-anyone-learned-how-to-program-in-21-days/441224#441224).

Comment: @BenBrocka I've gotten reputation points for it for every single upvote. :/ And I've recieved a few badges for it.

Comment: @PopularDemand, did he earn it before it went CW?

Comment: BTW, there's no reason that post should be CW (it was because of the edits).  That's been fixed for you (and rep recalced as well).

Comment: For the record, [Community wiki] still count towards badges (except tenacious and unsung hero, which explicitly don't count per the badge page)

Comment: When did it hit 40 votes?  Badges have delays on them...

Comment: @casperOne A little after the last edit.

Comment: @TylerCrompton, Bill's answer was converted to CW when the question collected 30 answers, on Jan. 14, 2009. His answer reached score of 40 (+41/-1) on August 19, 2010, the same day the badge was awarded to him. So, no, he did not earn it before it went CW. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/441198/timeline

Comment: So gave we confirmed that it is because of a self-accept?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Self-accepts are not eligible for the Guru badge. [Here's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) a non-CW example from tex.stackexchange.

Comment: All right; However, in the real life, if you self-answer life questions and obtain a lot of people that think you are right, we will call you a Guru.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to guess it's because it's a self-accept, but I can't find anything to back this up.

It was eligible more than 24h ago as far as I can tell, so I don't think time is the issue.
The CW status should not affect that badge.