# Fix Guru badge description

Tags: feature-request, wording, badge-description, guru-badge

Currently [Guru badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/18/guru) description looks as:

> Accepted answer and score of 40 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

According to the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120495/339911) that excludes self-accepted answers. Hence I suggest to clarify such a  nuance in the badge description. E.g. change the first sentence to the following:

> Accepted answer **by another user** and score of 40 or more.

This current feature request is not a duplicate of [another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189573/guru-badge-description) because the root part of this one - to point out that the **answer must be accepted by someone else**. This part doesn't mentioned at all in another FR.

Comment: Many badges don't have 'complete' descriptions (that's why we have the FAQ). Self-accepts are excluded from many badges (e.g. Enlightened).

Comment: @Glorfindel ofcourse in some complicated cases FAQ is necessary, but when fixing the description with a few words may clarify conditions to awarding the badge and prevent number of questions I think it should be implemented. More over to make such a fix no need to change any logic, just fix a single text string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Guru badge description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189573/guru-badge-description)

Comment: @CDR unfortunately, doesn't. Please read the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189573/guru-badge-description#comment1314218_189573).

Comment: The problem statement (that the description is ambiguous) in the other question is identical to yours. While the comment you linked does point out a flaw in the proposed solution, the question there states that it's simply an example solution. In my opinion, it's better to list alternate solutions as answers to the question, and it's not useful to have two different requests both attempting to address the same problem. See, for example, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366380/377214) to one of my feature requests.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Isn't that confusing? I assume FRs will be harder to find that way, but that also seems to go against very straightforward SE guidelines, in the sense that these are obviously different questions (even though the solutions to both could be implemented simultaneously). Both titles do need to be more explicit, though.

Comment: @Joachim Here on Meta.SE, questions can be closed as duplicates [even if they're merely related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/377214), if answers to the other question would address that question (see the final section there). Also, duplicates serve as signposts for searchability purposes, as mentioned there.

Comment: @Sonic if we close this question we can loss a point about **accepting by another user**. Hence I don't think they are duplicates.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ You can bring that point up as an answer there.

Comment: To me your suggestion makes it sound like the answer must be another user's answer. I do agree that it should be changed though, I would suggest something like "Accepted answer with score of 40 or more on another user's question".